# Parsing Excel of ASCII format in Perl

Tags: excel, perl

We have perl script whose job is to read an excel file and convert it into a flat file. We get excel file from some other system on a shared location.

The other system is generating a flat file dumping data in the file seperated by a tab and appending with .xls. Now the problem with that is since in xls file if there is a string with leading 0 e.g 012345 it will be displayed as 12345 in excel. To preseve the leading 0 what they do is they write the data in this fashion (in java)

```
"=\"" + some string + "\""
```

Now if we open the file in excel it is proper with no = or ", but when reading via perl it read the string as it is i.e. ="some string".

How can we work around this, i have tried a solution to trim the leading =" and " but do not feel it to be clen one. Can someont suggest anything else

Comment: Why is there a text file with a `.xls` ending? That should be a CSV file. Removing the `=` is just a trimming operation, you're right about that. If you want to contain the leading zero in Perl, don't do math operations with it. For anything else, show the Perl code.

Comment: I have no idea why text file is with .xls ending it is some other 3rd party system. Probably its because before placing the file on shared location it is shown to some front end users. So may be for some better presentment to front end user, they have chosen xls over csv.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (with the limited information you've given) would be to read the source file using Text::CSV, and then output via whatever means you would otherwise. For substitution, use regular expressions.

Simplified example (partially taken straight from the documentation):

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use Text::CSV;
# set binary attribute and use a tab as a separator:
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, sep_char => "\t"} )  
            or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.xls" or die "test.xls: $!";
my @rows;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    foreach my $column (@$row) {
        $column =~ s/^="|"$//g; # remove opening '="' and closing '"'
    }
    push @rows, $row;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
# do file writing magic or further processing here
```

In case you don't know, the 's' at the beginning of the regular expression indicates you want to substitue and the 'g' at the end means "repeat for all matches".

For more information, see:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html (Perl documentation on regular expressions)